# Tweak UML sequence diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlsd

I want to add some UML sequence diagrams in my document. This sequence contains many calls. That's why I want to tweak the diagram.

The following complete, but I hope minimal example shows only 5 (nested) calls in the diagram. I think the vertical distance between `StartCycle()` and `ActAgent()` should be reduced to a half or third. Similar the distance between the return arrows should be shrinked.

How can I control a the positioning of the elements?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[underline=true,rounded corners=false]{pgf-umlsd}

\usepackage{blindtext}
% It's possible to get a thin border around all figures. You have to write the following once at the beginning of the document:
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering  
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newthread{ss}{}{SimulationServer}
        \newinst[1]{ctr}{}{SimControlNode}
        \newinst[1]{ps}{}{PhysicsServer}
        \newinst[1]{sense}{}{SenseServer}

        \begin{call}{ss}{Initialize()}{sense}{}
        \end{call}
        \begin{sdblock}{}{Run Loop}
            \begin{call}{ss}{StartCycle()}{ctr}{}
                \begin{call}{ctr}{ActAgent()}{sense}{}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
            \begin{call}{ss}{EndCycle()}{ctr}{}
                \begin{call}{ctr}{SenseAgent()}{sense}{}
                \end{call}
            \end{call}
        \end{sdblock}
    \end{sequencediagram}

    \caption{UML sequence diagram demo.}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I tried adding a `\renewcommand\unitfactor{0.4}` in the `sequencediagram` environment. But this applies to all distances and causes the call designators like "EndCycle()" to overlay return paths.

Answer (score 1):

This tweak is unfortunately impossible. The implementation of the current version 0.7 (dated in 2013) uses counters to create a kind of grid. Each new position is calculated by using

```
\stepcounter{counter}
```

what places the position down by one (1.0) lines. The logic does not provides customizable spaces.